# area bounded by the curves $y=\left |x-1 \right |$ and $x^2 +y^2=2x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

Find the area bounded by the curves  $y=\left |x-1  \right |$ and $x^2 +y^2=2x$.(Where, $y \geqslant0 $)

I know the general rule of solving this problem.But the limit is so peculiar.Is there any short to find the area.

Comment: Sketch it out, and then take the integral...

Answer (score 2):

First "curve" is an angle -a right one, in fact- with vertex in $(1,0)$. And the second curve is a circle centered precisely in that point and radius $1$.

So the area is $\pi/4$.